# How to reduce this algebraic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Having a bit of difficulty remembering how to reduce this expression:

$\frac{b^{3} -3a^{2}b + 2a^{3}}{4[b^{2} - 2ab + a^{2}]}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

I'm sure I learned this in algebra class in high school at some point but it's slipped my mind at the moment. I know the expression reduces to $2a +b$

Comment: Without the $4$ in the denominator it would.  [Polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{b^{3} -3a^{2}b + 2a^{3}}{4[b^{2} - 2ab + a^{2}]} & = \frac{b^3 - a^3 + 3a^3 - 3a^2b}{4(b-a)^2} \\
& = \frac{(b-a)(b^2 +ab +a^2) - 3a^2(b-a)}{4(b-a)^2} \\
& = \frac{b^2 + ab-2a^2}{4(b-a)} \\
& = \frac{(b+2a)(b-a)}{4(b-a)} \\
& = \frac{2a+b}{4}.
\end{align}